# Using ui-typeahead to populate model with object but show string of that model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

Hello everyone I have the following code using ui-angular typeahead

```
<input type="text" ng-model="itemSelected"
           uib-typeahead="item.name for item in getItems()" id="itemInput" class="form-control">
```

the data that `getItems()` returns is of this structure:

> [{itemId : 12345, name : "name of item"} ....]

Now what I would like to happen is the type ahead to give it's suggestions by showing `item.name` (which it currently does!) however what it does is sets itemSelected to the string not the object.

if I change the html such that the list comprehension reads item for item in `getItems()` I get the typeahead giving me the object (not what I want) although it does set the itemSelected variable to the object of my selected typeahead.

I would like the typeahead to display item.name but I would like the object item to be put into `itemSelected`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following...it works fine

https://plnkr.co/edit/Zsgw5RKAEi5C2IKLcpGR?p=preview

```
<div>seleted state: {{state4}}</div>
        <input type="text" ng-change="onedit()"  ng-model="state4" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

Comment: I agree it works fine but that is not taking in an array of objects which is what i am doing, getItems() in my example returns an array of objects with members of itemId and name. I want the typeahead to display the name but i want the model of the input to store the object so that i can later query by the id not the name of the item.

Comment: even in my example it is array of objects...
$scope.states = [{name:"Pankaj",id:2},{name:"Pankaj1",id:3},
        {name:"Pankaj4",id:4},{name:"Pankaj5",id:5},{name:"Pankaj6",id:6},
        {name:"Pankaj7",id:7},{name:"Pankaj8",id:8},{name:"Pankaj9",id:9}];

Comment: The plunker does not have that ?

Comment: i see a js file with states in that plunkr

Comment: an array of strings to be precise, are you sure you updated the original version?

Comment: Yeh you r right...wait i will give u the updated one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117464/discussion-between-user1383163-and-pankaj-kumar).

Comment: Works fine, completely missed the "state as state.name" part and instead went for "state for state" I really should have picked up on this one. Thanks